# Are Dylibs in iOS Appstore apps?

Tags: ios, app-store, shared-libraries, dylib, dlopen

In 2021, ios 11 and above, does the app store still reject an app that ships and uses a dylib via dlopen during the review phase?

I've looked around and haven't found any new answers or definitve answers.
I also found this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1
where it says Note: The creation and use of loadable bundles is not supported in iOS.
but since it's archived I'm not sure if I should trust it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes, via Frameworks only